# CS0161: 'ProductModel.GetProducts(int)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting compilation error in following code, please help:

```
 private Product GetProduct(int id)        
    {
        try
        {
            using (CoffeeDBEntities db = new CoffeeDBEntities())
            {
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the Product

```
private Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product product =new Product();
    try
    {
        using (CoffeeDBEntities db = new CoffeeDBEntities())
        {
            product = db.Products.Find(id);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: You should return the product*, not the type of product.
Would your code compile with 2 declarations of product?

Answer (score 0):

You only `return` if you `catch` the exception. how about

```
try
{
    using (CoffeeDBEntities db = new CoffeeDBEntities())
    {
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        return product;
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you there is a path through your method that does not return any values. That path is the successful path of the try block. You need to return your Product object.

Change the code to the following

```
try
{
    using (CoffeeDBEntities db = new CoffeeDBEntities())
    {
        return db.Products.Find(id);
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return a Product in your method. Do like this.

```
{
    Product product=new Product();
    try
    {
        using (CoffeeDBEntities db = new CoffeeDBEntities())
        {
            product = db.Products.Find(id);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Tell me, If it helps